# How to stop tracking files in gitignore with untracked files still in repository?

Tags: git

How can I untrack files in git, but leave the untracked files in repository? 
To better understand that problem let me show an example: I have a git repository with my project and I want to add wordpress to subdirectory. I want to have base wordpress files in git repository, change them a bit, commit them and then stop tracking every file in wordpress directory but without them being removed from repository. How can I do that?

Comment: `git rm --cached <files>` is what you want, here: it will stop tracking `<files>` but will *not* remove them from your working tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git rm --cached -- <files>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

> **--cached**
>
> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether > modified or not, will be left alone.

Usually `git rm` affects both index and working tree but with `--cached` the working tree is left alone.